# Conversion from string to object in Windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, deserialization, windows-8.1

I want to covert to string into object with value. I mean let's say i have string that has XML code inside like:

```
string response = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Response>
<ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
<ResultMessage>success</ResultMessage>
<Body>
<Rooms>
        <Room>
              <RoomID>room1@nxdev.com</RoomID>
              <RoomName>White Room</RoomName>
              <Capacity>10</Capicity>
              <Equipments>Beam Projector, VTR</Equipments>
              <Reservations>
                   <Reservation>
                        <StartDT> 2014-02-18 14:00</StartDT>
                        <EndDT>2014-02-18 15:00</EndDT>
                        <UserName>Jhon</UserName>
                        <Subject>Project Meeting</Subject>
                   <Reservation>
              </Reservatoins>
        </Room>
    </Rooms>
</Body>
</Response>"
```

I have a Class that has all the properties which mentioned in Xml like

```
[XmlRoot("Response")]
public class Response 
{
    string ResultCode {get; set; }
    string ResutlMessage { get; set; }
}

public class RoomListResponse : Response
{
   List<Room> rooms { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
   [XmlElement("RoomID")]
   string RoomID { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("RoomName")]
   string RoomName { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("Capacity")]
   string Capacity { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("Equipments")]
   string Equipments { get; set; } 

   List<Reservation> Reservations;
}
public class Reservations
{
   [XmlElement("StartDT")]
   string StartDT { get; set; } 
   [XmlElement("EndDT")]
   string EndDT { get; set; } 
   [XmlElement("UserName")]
   string UserName { get; set; } 
   [XmlElement("Subject")]
   string Subject { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I set all the values in RoomListResponse object without string parsing? I have tried it with serialization but it gives me some problem in windows 8.1 app store project due to limitation in API.

Is there any way to get it sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is the only way.

In your case you might want to try replacing the

```
List<Reservation> Reservations;
```

by

```
[XmlElement("Reservations")]
Reservation [] Reservations;
```

and then use the XmlSerializer